# Dropdown menu positioning and styling

Tags: html, css

How do I make it so that the hover effects are full width of the dropdown and so that the text changes  colour on hovering on the li not the a.

So it should be a black dropdown menu, when each link is hovered on the background of the li should change to `rgba(255,255,255, 0.1)` and the text should change to `rgba(102,245,66, 0.8)` the li and a sections shouldn't overflow the normal dropdown section (I tried `overflow: hidden`)

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  min-width: 240px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: .5em;
  height: 75px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: $main-font;
  width: 240px;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgba(102, 245, 66, 0.8);
}

li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  color: #8FC3A1;
  width: 240px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span><i class="fa fa-bars">Just hover on it</i></span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#lin">Line Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: If not. then change a to {display: block;} and move all size defining props from li to a or use absolute full width a:before or a:after to fill full li element. 
If using bootstrap, then just change classes to fit bootstrap version usage standarts.

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/Cd18yN4540/bootstrap-4-mega-menu-full-width
Hope this helps

Comment: @andris not using bootstrap I tried changing it to display: block and moving all the size based stylings, it didn't work.

Comment: Are you looking for `li:hover { background-color: ... } li:hover a { color: ... }` ?

Comment: The problem with @Awais fix is that the hover effect still doesn't fill the whole li

Comment: update my ans please have a look @MacHooper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this i m not pretty much sure, please do let me know if it fulfills you requirement, the solution is change color of `a` when we hover `li`

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  min-width: 240px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
      left: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.1);
  color: #8FC3A1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover a{
  color: rgba(102,245,66, 0.8)
}


a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: $main-font;
  width: 240px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span><i class="fa fa-bars">fa-bar dropdown</i></span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#lin">Line Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```